# How Visual Studio displays controls in the toolbox depending on the document open

Tags: visual-studio-2010, user-controls, designer, toolbox, visual-studio-sdk

I wanted to know how Visual Studio Toolbox displays only a sub-set of Controls of all the controls depending on the document open. Document can be any file, for example, when WindowsForms is open, any component that can be dropped appears on the toolbox.

How does Visual Studio does it?

I have Visual Studio SDK installed. How do I know which tabs are hidden and which tabs are displayed. (Of course "Show All.." is unchecked).

Thanks!!

-Datte

Comment: isn't that called programming? visual studio is one of the best programs one have ever seen.

Comment: I know. Some microsoft guy would have programmed how VisualStudio's Toolbox should show the controls based on what document (file) the user has open, in Visual Studio's desginer. 

Visual Studio's SDK is rich enough to allow users to manipulate the VS's Toolbox. I wanted to know how does one can show/hide controls in the Toolbox of Visual Studio (not a toolbox control in a winform app).